# Measure of the proximity of two sets in a non-metric space?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

I am asking a question out of some practical concern.
For example, consider the collection of all letters of alphabets, $S = \{a, b, \dotsb, z\}$.
Consider two subsets $A, B, C \subset S$ such that:

$A = \{a, b, c\}$,
$B = \{b, c, d\}$, and
$C = \{x, y, z\}$.

I think many of us would think that intuitively the set $B$ is more similar to $A$ than it is to $C$.

Is there a widely used index that summarizes this kind of similarity between two sets?

Comment: A finite set can be viewed as bit string and you can use the Hamming distance

Comment: what is the "practical oncern"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is a finite set, then you can define a metric on the set of subsets of $S$ by setting
$$
d(X, Y) = |X \def\symdiff{\mathop{\triangle}} \symdiff Y| = |X| + |Y| - 2|X \cap Y|
$$
where $\symdiff(X, Y) = (X \cup Y) \setminus (X \cap Y)$ is the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of $X$ and $Y$, and $|Z|$ is the number of elements of $Z$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128733/proof-of-metric) for a proof that it is indeed a metric.

In your case, you would have $d(A, B) = 2$ and $d(B, C) = 6$, which corresponds to your intuition, but contrary to your title, it can be defined with a metric.

Comment: If you represent the sets as binary strings this is the hamming distance of two strings.